# ошибка h264 @ 000002bc10abc4c0 при обнаружении предмемтов YoloV5 и Opencv

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning

написал скрипт, который обнаружает предметы в прямой трансляции. работает несколько минут и вылетает с ошибкой "[h264 @ 000002bc10abc4c0] error while decoding MB 71 11, bytestream -7"
ограничивал FPS - не помогло, уменьшил качество изображения до 640*640 тоже не помогло, что можно еще испробовать?
код ниже:

```
import datetime
from ultralytics import YOLO
import cv2

CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD = 0.8
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)


video_cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp:..")




model = YOLO(r'best.pt')

while True:
    
    start = datetime.datetime.now()

    ret, frame = video_cap.read()

    
    if not ret:
        break
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 640))
    
    detections = model(frame)[0]

    for data in detections.boxes.data.tolist():
        
        confidence = data[4]

        if float(confidence) < CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD:
            continue

        
        xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = int(data[0]), int(data[1]), int(data[2]), int(data[3])
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (xmin, ymin), (xmax, ymax), GREEN, 2)

    end = datetime.datetime.now()

    
    total = (end - start).total_seconds()
    

    
    fps = f"FPS: {1 / total:.2f}"
    cv2.putText(frame, fps, (50, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (0, 0, 255), 8)

    
    cv2.imshow("Yolov5", frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
        break


video_cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```